# insert text in the sections of circle in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot something heatmap in a circular form. I am using matplotlib to do this, I took some example given here and modified it to plot mine. I am able to get till this point the circle and able to fill the colors in each sections of the circle.

Now, I want insert text in each section indicating what it is. Can anyone help me understand how to print text in a circular form?

Also, since my values are between 0.7-0.8, I am getting shades of gray but with very little difference. Is there a way in which I can scale up my color bar so that difference is more prominent?

Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab
from matplotlib.projections import PolarAxes


labels = ['A1A2', 'B1B2', 'F1F2', 'P1P2'] #innerCircle
labels2 = ['A1P1', 'B1P1', 'F1P1', 'F1P1','A2P2', 'B2P2',   'F2P2','F2P2']#outecircle

I = [0.77147898831281592, 0.77754754203464382, 0.7730316051917463,  0.75265521526987844] #innerCircle
O = [0.82767052973376798, 0.77921788065668873, 0.82932467288645262, 0.82932467288645262,0.80286007268622095, 0.78757118956065952, 0.79434911322895663, 0.79434911322895663] #outecircle

newN = []
for i in O:
    j = float(i)
    newN.append(j*1000)

print newN
maxN = round(max(newN))
print maxN

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = 'polar')
subplot(111,projection='polar')
theta = arange(maxN)*2*pi/maxN


plot(theta,0.25*ones(maxN),'k') 
plot(theta, 0.65*ones(maxN), 'k') 
plot([0, 0],[0,0.65],'k') 
plot([pi/4.,pi/4.],[0.25, 0.65], 'k')
plot([pi/2, pi/2.],[0, 0.65], 'k')
plot([3*pi/4.,3*pi/4],[0.25, 0.65], 'k')
plot([pi,pi],[0,0.65],'k') 
plot([5*pi/4,5*pi/4],[0.25, 0.65], 'k') 
plot([3*pi/2,3*pi/2],[0, 0.65], 'k') 
plot([7*pi/4,7*pi/4],[0.25, 0.65], 'k') 


ax.add_artist(Wedge((0.5,0.5), 0.325, 0,45, width=0.2,    transform=ax.transAxes, color=str(O[0])))
ax.add_artist(Wedge((0.5,0.5), 0.325, 45,90, width=0.2,    transform=ax.transAxes, color=str(O[1])))
ax.add_artist(Wedge((0.5,0.5), 0.325, 90,135, width=0.2, transform=ax.transAxes, color=str(O[2])))
ax.add_artist(Wedge((0.5,0.5), 0.325, 135,180, width=0.2, transform=ax.transAxes, color=str(O[3])))
ax.add_artist(Wedge((0.5,0.5), 0.325, 180,225, width=0.2, transform=ax.transAxes, color=str(O[4])))
ax.add_artist(Wedge((0.5,0.5), 0.325, 225,270, width=0.2, transform=ax.transAxes, color=str(O[5])))
ax.add_artist(Wedge((0.5,0.5), 0.325, 270,315, width=0.2, transform=ax.transAxes, color=str(O[6])))
ax.add_artist(Wedge((0.5,0.5), 0.325, 315,360, width=0.2, transform=ax.transAxes, color=str(O[7])))

ax.add_artist(Wedge((0.5,0.5), 0.125, 0,90, width=0.125, transform=ax.transAxes, color = str(I[0])))
ax.add_artist(Wedge((0.5,0.5), 0.125, 90,180, width=0.125, transform=ax.transAxes, color = str(I[1])))
ax.add_artist(Wedge((0.5,0.5), 0.125, 180,270, width=0.125, transform=ax.transAxes, color = str(I[2])))
ax.add_artist(Wedge((0.5,0.5), 0.125, 270,360, width=0.125, transform=ax.transAxes, color = str(I[3])))

ax.grid(False)
rgrids((1,1),('',''))


ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.set_theta_direction('clockwise')         

show()
```

Thanks!

I want something like this:
[image: What I Want]

And so far I have reached till here:
[image: What I Have So Far]

I also need to get rid of the outer white circle and degrees.

Thanks!

Comment: Just link to the image if you do not have sufficient reputation to include it, and someone can then edit your question to inline the image.

Comment: No problem, but sure that the links work publicly.  `file:///` links will only work on your machine; links that start with `http://` or `https://` are what you want.  Anywhere you can put an image online and share it with a publicly accessible link will do.  Some people use Imgur I believe, but take your pick.

Comment: Thanks J0egan! I created links with imgur.

Comment: I inlined the images and cleaned up the question text a bit.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the labels:

```
halfwedge = np.pi/8
for i in range(8):
    ax.text(np.pi/2 - halfwedge*(2*i+1), 0.425, labels2[i])

for i in range(4):
    ax.text(np.pi/2 - halfwedge*2*(2*i+1), 0.15, labels[i])
```

To get a grip on the coordinate systems:

```
ax.text(0,0,'0,0 transAxes',transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(0,1,'0,1 transAxes',transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(.5,0,'.5,0 transAxes',transform=ax.transAxes)

ax.text(0,1,'0,1 transData', transform=ax.transData)
ax.text(0,0,'0,0 transData', transform=ax.transData)
ax.text(np.pi/2,1,'pi/2,1 transData', transform=ax.transData)
ax.text(np.pi,0.5,'pi,0.5 transData', transform=ax.transData)
ax.text(np.pi*3/2,1,'3pi/2,1 transData', transform=ax.transData)
```

and really you want all those ax.add_artist lines in a loop, and the labels too!

To turn off the axis:

```
ax.spines['polar'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
```

and to make the colors more distinct, look up colormaps -- you can set the upper and lower bounds of the data to increase the possible spread of the colors.

[image: Labels all over polar plot]

Comment: Thanks cphlewis! I appreciate your help. I used these options   ax.text(0.55, 0.55, labels[1],horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(0.45, 0.45, labels[2],horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',transform=ax.transAxes)

Comment: Why? If you're doing a polar plot, go ahead and use polar coordinates. Look how much shorter the assignments measured in half-wedges are.

Comment: With this I am getting this figure. http://imgur.com/CfjjCul

I want to know what is the first two parameters in ax.text() I randomly fed these numbers to get the text at particular position.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look at the sample code labelled "To get a grip on the coordinate systems" and look at the difference between transAxes and transData lines. The axis is in Cartesian coordinates, usually called x,y. The data *in a polar plot* is in polar coordinates, usually called theta, r. Theta is in radians so 2*pi is a full circle, and theta=0 is straight up. 

Your wedges are added with 0 degrees (that's 0-360) pointing right; I've adjusted the text-adding to match.

Comment: Thanks cphlewis! I understood the coordinates system now. Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Cool. If you think this answers your question, you can checkmark it as an accepted answer -- this makes the site a little better organized, and gives me egoboost/stackoverflow points.